# Detect long press on UIWebview and pop up a menu if I'm pressing on a link

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Running into a problem with UIWebview, it doesn't seem to react to gesture recognizer. I would like to get a popover to appear whenever I do a long press on a link (or image) with different actions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated =). Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

You can detect clicking on a URL like this

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

   if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {  
   NSURL *URL = [request URL];  
   if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http://"]) {    
      //It is a URL

   }else{  
       //Not a URL  
   }  
   return YES;

}
```

Comment: I mean still pressing on the link, no touch up event is fired yet.

Comment: if the control is coming to shouldStartLoadWithRequest,check the navigationType.

Comment: -1. We are concerned about how to detect the **long press** event rather than the simple **click** event. But this answer did nothing about it.