# Downloading and saving an image from link in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to save an image to the photo library from a website which is opened in an uiwebview.The link is not just an image link where NSURLConnection can be used to download.I want to achieve the download by long pressing the image in UIWebView  just as it can be done in safari. How can i achieve this..is it possible??

Comment: I think this is the one you are looking for.. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009760/detect-long-press-on-uiwebview-and-pop-up-a-menu-if-im-pressing-on-a-link?rq=1>

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *response = NULL;

NSError *requestError = NULL;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the response string contains complete information

Comment: This holds good if an item is to be downloaded from a known url..how can that be achieved from uiwebview having dynamic images and links

Comment: @AppleDelegate: u can get the content of webview using this NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@\"document.documentElement.textContent\"]; or u can get it by NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to ask, but why do you use an UIWebView to only load an image. The UIImageView class constructor imageWithContentsOfURL: would do the job perfect.

Then you can just use an UIPopoverController for presenting a UIViewController with an UIButton calling UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (http://goo.gl/uAJYS) to save the UIImage from your UIImageView directly into the users camera roll.

For Optimisation use an UITableViewController instead of the UIViewController - more the default iOS look&feel - and present the UIPopoverController with a small delay by overwriting the UIResponder methods on the UIImageView.

// EDIT: If you really mean how to get the exact behaviour of the Safari to save any image in the dom tree, i am a bit stumped. Maybe someone else can contribute some information on that.

Comment: actually its a website is opened in the UIWebView,its not just about loading a single image ,im dealing with a website with number of images opened into webview

Comment: what about parsing the html code and extracting all the img urls, presenting them separately on UIImageViews and than go the described way?

Comment: Yes, maaalex give some nice idea of extracting image url from UIWebView.

Comment: @maaalex:but wont that be an inappropriate way,because the html code can be huge in case of some websites.

Comment: If it is your website you want to save the images from, you can define a url-scheme, link the images with that scheme and the absolute URL as parameter, overwrite the shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method of your webview and handle the img download and save to camera roll there.
@iHungry: Should perform nice with a regex expression